# How to copy active text from google docs to spreadsheet with menu item/option

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, google-docs

I'm fairly new to google apps and I know that similar questions have been asked but they only adress similar problems. I hope you can help me.

I want to copy an active text from a google docs to a given spreadsheet via a button. I've done similar for spreadsheet to spreadsheet but I'm failing on docs to spreadsheet.

```
function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Copy active Range.')
        .addItem('Copy Button', 'Copy')
        .addToUi();
}

function Copy() {
    var ss = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var selection = ss.getSelection();

    var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById("xxx");
    var ts = tss.getSheetByName("name");

    trange = ts.getRange("B6:B6")
    selection.copyto(trange);
}
```

Thanks in advance to everyone investing time thinking about my problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try this code

```
var SPREADSHEET_ID = "YYYY"; // = assign your spreadsheet id to this variable
var SHEET_NAME = "XXXXX"; // = assign your sheet name to this variable

function onOpen(e) {
    DocumentApp.getUi()
        .createMenu('Copy active Range.')
        .addItem('Copy Button', 'Copy')
        .addToUi();
}

function Copy() {
    var ss = DocumentApp.getActiveDocument();
    var selection = ss.getSelection();
    var result = "";

    //Proceed only if something is selected, otherwise selection will be null
    if (selection) {

        var elements = selection.getRangeElements();
        for (var i = 0; i < elements.length; i++) {
            var element = elements[i];

            // Only modify elements that can be edited as text; skip images and other non-text elements.
            if (element.getElement().editAsText) {
                result += element.getElement().asText().getText();
            }
        }

        var tss = SpreadsheetApp.openById(SPREADSHEET_ID);
        var ts = tss.getSheetByName(SHEET_NAME);

        trange = ts.getRange(2, 6); //I think, you can use B6 also
        trange.setValue(result);
    }


}
```

This is not a tested code let me know if any error pops ups. I'll happy to debug together.

If it works, accepts/upvote this answer so that other people can also get help from this.

Comment: No error pops up and text is inserted into the right cell("B6:B6" also works) but it is always inserting the word "Range" instead of the active text.

Comment: Thanks, Umair! The updated script is working perfectly fine.

Comment: Cool! @JoeL31 you can upvote this answer so that other people can also benefit from this.

Comment: Yes, I already upvoted. It will be upvoted as soon as I hit 15 reputation

Comment: Ok! Best of luck to us!